# Netsuite casetaskevent value not accepted

Tags: netsuite

I'm taking over an existing setup and trying to update a form by added a new option for the user. I need to have `casetaskevent` set to a value but when I attempt to process it like this:

```
timebillRec.setValue ({
  fieldId: 'casetaskevent',
  value: taskid,
  ignoreFieldChange: true
})
```

I get the error: `You have entered an Invalid Field Value 673 for the following field: casetaskevent`

I think the person before me set acceptable values for `casetaskevent` but I can't for the life of me figure out where that's set. Based on docs, this is a standard id I'm targeting for timebill.

Where can I updated the accepted values?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that your `casetaskevent` field has a filter set in the "Sourcing & Filtering" tab.

[image]

That means that you can only set values that match this filter.